# Where should the batch processes of an e commerce website be kept in the same application or different application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications, e-commerce

My  question is do we need to keep customer functionalities and daily processing of products, payments in different application or server or port number?I Have not found any articles  in Google whether we should keep processes such as checking whether a product is expired and also checking whether vendor is eligible for payment in the same application where we show customers products and various other e commerce functionalities or do we keep all the batch process in different application or different port number or different server? I am a beginner in building e commerce websites any links or best practice recommendations would be great

Comment: this is a question about size more than anything,

the bigger you are the more normal processes of your website will cause things to lag - if you are not processing more than 120(ish) things a second you should be fine to keep it in the one place but if you are having speed issues maybe look at AWS - Elastic Beanstalk as a solution keeps all on the same server but when it gets crowded it will spin up a new server to handle the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study and watch Clean Code Lectures by Robert Martin. Study about Microservices. Study about building good APIs. The idea is that to start with your application is going to be monolithic.  Its not practical to build 10 different applications at the same time. But then as you build out you should refactor and split them up. The other big idea is that even if its just the credit card transactions to start with - your application will be interacting with 3rd parties. And as you grow you will be interacting with more external APIs.

However one area where it should be immediately split up - I would strongly recommend keeping your Order/Product Admin applications completely separate from the Public ecommmerce shopping application. This will simplify the security concerns which are very different, and the User Roles which are also very different.